# If $|G|=p^n$ where $p$ is prime and $n\geq1$, please show that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial

Tags: group-theory

$|G|=p^n$ where $p$ is prime and $n\geq1$. Show that if $G$ acts on a set
$X$, and $Y$ is an orbit of this action, then either $|Y| = 1$ or $p$ divides $|Y|$.
Show that $|Z(G)| >1$.

By considering the set of elements of $G$ that commute with a fixed element $x\notin Z(G)$, show that $Z(G)$ cannot have order $p^{n-1}$.

for the first part of this question,I can see |Y|=1 or |Y||p follows from orbit and stabilizer theorem. And consider G acts on itself by conjugation, Z(G) is actually the stabilizer. I got this because intended to show Z(G) is non-trivial by showing orbit can't contain all elements but I didn't find a way to work out. I got stuck here and would be thankful if anyone can help.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions on similar topics. You might consider taking a bit of time to digest the answers you get before posting more.

Answer (score 1):

Making $\,G\,$ act on itself by conjugation and noting that

$$x\in Z(G)\Longleftrightarrow |\mathcal Orb(x)|=1$$

we get the *class equation* for $\,G\,$:

$$p^n=|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{x\notin Z(G)}|\mathcal Orb(x)|$$

where the sum is over different, and thus pairwise disjoint, conjugation classes.

But $\,|\mathcal Orb(x)|=[G:G_x]\,\,,\,G_x=$ the stabilizer subgroup of $\,x\,$ , and thus all the summands of the sum in the class equation are multiples of $\,p\,$ (in fact, powers of it), so that **it must be** that $\,|Z(G)|>1\,$ .

For the second part, prove the nice

**Proposition:** For any group $\,G\,$ , if $\,G/Z(G)\,$ is cyclic non-trivial then $\,G\,$ is abelian, or in otherwords: the quotient $\,G/Z(G)\,$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

By orbit decomposition formula $\mathrm{card}(Y)=\sum_{G_s}|G:G_s|$ Since $p\mid\lvert G:G_s\rvert$, $p\mid\mathrm{card}(Y)$

For the part $|Z(G)|>1$, use class equation 
$$|G|=|Z(G)|+ \sum_{\substack{\text{non-trivial}\\\text{conjugacy }\\\text{classes }G_x}}|G:G_x|,$$
 $p\mid\lvert G\rvert$ and $p\mid\lvert G:G_x\rvert$
hence $p\mid\lvert Z(G)\rvert$ so $\lvert Z(G)\rvert>1$

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I am trying to help you by formatting your post with LaTeX for you. Even if you want to add to your post later, please at least don't undo the work I did.